# RxSwift/RxCocoa: prevent UITextField from having more than ... characters

Tags: swift, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

I would like to have a UITextField configured with RxSwift/RxCocoa so that it only contains up to ... characters. I do not want to use the `UITextFieldDelegate` for this but would love to achieve this with RxSwift/RxCocoa. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Sure:

```
textField.rx.controlEvent(.editingChanged).subscribe(onNext: { [unowned self] in
    if let text = self.textField.text {
        self.textField.text = String(text.prefix(40))
    }
}).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

In this example, the textfield is limited to 40 characters.

Edit:

Keeping the previous value when the limit is reached.

```
textField.rx.text.orEmpty
.scan("") { (previous, new) -> String in
    if new.count > 40 {
        return previous ?? String(new.prefix(40))
    } else {
        return new
    }
}
.subscribe(textField.rx.text)
.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

This can probably be adapted to respect other rules...

Please note however that when reaching the character limit, your cursor will jump to the end of the textField.

Comment: That's close, but not exactly what I'm looking for. E.g. if the text field has 40 characters and the user types a character at the beginning I would like to prevent that and let the content unchanged, in your case the new character is taken and the last one disappears.

Comment: Edited my post to answer your extra criteria. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Valérian for your edited answer, the `String(new.prefix(40))` in `return previous ?? String(new.prefix(40))` will never execute, the `previous` value will never be nil so why you are adding it?

Comment: Unfortunately, the compiler makes previous optional because `textField.rx.text` expects an optional string. You can get rid of this by adding `.map { Optional($0) }` between `scan` and `subscribe`.

Comment: @Valérian  `previous` isn't optional and it will never be! What i meant is that there is no meaning for `String(new.prefix(40))` and it will never be executed since previous isn't optional ,You have make it non optional by seeding the `Scan` with empty string `scan("")`...

Comment: While I agree with you in theory, using the above code in my project, the compiler considers it as optional when it shouldn't. Have you tried on your side ?

Comment: Yes @Valérian , mine it considers it as non-optional.

Comment: How to get UITextfield's typing character in Rxswift ? Can anyone help me?

Comment: @Valérian For example the textfield is initially blank and then the limit is 2 chars. If programmatically I set the value like this: textfield.text = "123". Textfield will still be blank. How can it get "12" instead?

Comment: Setting the text like you mention doesn't trigger a control event so you probably have something else going on. You can add debug operators in the sequence to confirm that.

Comment: True. `.scan("") { previous, new in   (new.count > 40) ? previous : new  }` is enough.

Answer (score 1):

**Example with 10 characters limit:**

```
textField.rxText.orEmpty.map { String($0.prefix(10)) }
        .bind(to: textField.rxText)
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```